# Python: Reading single big .gz file consumes more memory than several smal files

Tags: python, json, memory, gzip

I have a json file with several millions of rows, compressed to .gz. When I read the full file I run out of memory.

So I split the file in multiple files, each 100k rows, compress all of them to .gz and read them all in a loop. No memory problems.

Now I think, that in both cases I read exact the same amount of rows in memory, but the one file approach runs out of memory.

Could somebody elaborate why?

Comment: Maybe you're close to the memory limit, or maybe you did something odd in your code. Which we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you have a single file, you open and store in your RAM the full content of the file, whereas while using a loop, you process files one by one. If done properly (as it looks like you do), your program will close each file and free the allocated memory before opening the next one, hence reducing the necessary RAM to run the program and avoiding to run out of memory.

Comment: Maybe. Depends on how they do it. If they use `json.load(file)`, I could imagine there being only a very small overhead. Even if they use `json.loads(file.read())`, the string probaably still takes much less memory that the parsed structure of objects.

Comment: Hmpf... disappointingly, `json.load(file)` appears to be implemented as `return json.loads(file.read())`. But the string is still likely relatively small, so I'm back to my original suspicion that they're close to the limit (so that loading the string for all data into memory makes a difference).